# What is the best way to reverse engineer a custom SharePoint list with custom content type?

Tags: content-type, reverse-engineering

What is the best way to reverse engineer a custom SharePoint List with a custom content type attached to it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "reverse engineer". Can you edit this question to let us know what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, or a subtle restatement of

http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/8085/is-there-any-updated-version-of-spsource-or-alternative-tool-for-sharepoint-2010

Comment: reverse engineer here means taking the existing custom list with content type attached to a WSP so that it can be easily deploy to another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010, preferrably with the [Community Kit for SharePoint Developer Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee876627-962c-4c35-a4a6-a4d89bfb61dc). This allows you to browse in the Server Explorer down to your list, content type or fields, and you can right click and 'import' them into your Visual Studio project. This then shows you the CAML used to define those items.

Another alternative is SharePoint manager - it also exposes the XML used to define those elements - but I find the Visual Studio tools more useful, 'cos generally I want to do something with those lists/content types.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is me just not getting the question, but look at the List Settings through the UI?